# Rally API Add Tags to existing userstory NodeJS

Tags: node.js, tags, rally

I have been stuck on this issue for a while and I finally ended up asking on here. I need an example on how to add existing tags on existing test case using the NodeJS rally api. I have already seen the Java implementation and it does not help me too much.

I already have an application which creates/updates test cases, test folders, etc. I just got an extra requirement to add tags. I have been looking at their APIs and I am so confused on how to attach the tags. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this section in the user guide:

https://github.com/RallyTools/rally-node/wiki/User-Guide#add-to-a-collection

That code example is adding defects to a story, but it should be super straightforward to change that to tags...

Comment: Thank you. I saw that, but I guess it just passed my mind. I got it to work though. Thanks again.