# rally-node Add new item to collection

Tags: node.js, rally

Using the rally-node toolkit, I'm getting an error message returned when attempting to add new Changeset, with new Changes inline, to an existing Userstory. When I have the new Changes commented out there's the Changeset is added as expected. It seems to be something specifically with the Change data that I can't figure out.

Add call:

```js
rallyApi.add({  
  "ref":"https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/hierarchicalrequirement/91834286580",
  "collection":"Changesets",
  "data":[  
    {  
      "Author":{  
        "_ref":"https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/user/53634054872"
      },
      "CommitTimestamp":"2017-03-17T09:52:07-04:00",
      "Message":"Feature/tags (#11)",
      "Revision":"b8460460254cb79d3e72c98172c164f5c4d3493a",
      "Uri":"https://ghe/org/repo/commit/b8460460254cb79d3e72c98172c164f5c4d3493a",
      "Changes":[
        {
          "Action":"M",
          "PathAndFilename":"file1.json",
          "Uri":"https://ghe/org/repo/commit/b8460460254cb79d3e72c98172c164f5c4d3493a/file1.json"
        },
        {
          "Action":"M",
          "PathAndFilename":"file2.json",
          "Uri":"https://ghe/org/repo/commit/b8460460254cb79d3e72c98172c164f5c4d3493a/file2.json"
        }
      ],
      "SCMRepository":{
  "_ref":"https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/scmrepository/101417587520"
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

Returned error:

`{ [Error: Could not create artifact to collection]
  errors: 
   [ 'Could not create artifact to collection',
     'Cannot parse object reference from "{null: {"Action": "M", "PathAndFilename": "file1.json", "Uri": "https://ghe/org/repo/commit/b8460460254cb79d3e72c98172c164f5c4d3493a/file1.json"}}"' ] }`

It seems to be telling me it tried to find an existing change with that data, but I want to add a new change as specified in the docs and a recent question:

https://github.com/RallyTools/rally-node/wiki/User-Guide#add-to-a-collection

[Rally API Add Tags to existing userstory NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42842129/rally-api-add-tags-to-existing-userstory-nodejs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do all of these things at the same time (although that would be pretty cool).

I'd first use the add method to add the changeset like you have specified, but without any changes.  And then use the add method again to create the changes on that changeset.  Does that work?

Comment: Yeah that was the direction I went, and that works. Thanks for confirming that my original proposal isn't something supported in the current library.